# IncompatibleClassChangeError while running Stanford NER and Stanford POS tagger

Tags: java, exception, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use Stanford NER and Stanford POS tagger in one application. I am getting `IncompatibleClassChangeError` when I try to run POS tagger method.

I have jar files of both NER and POS tagger in the class path. If I remove jar of NER from my classpath then this error is not coming. I guess there are some classes common in NER jar and POS jar and java is not able to determine which class to be used at runtime.

Following is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.init(MaxentTagger.java:407)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:699)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:673)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:280)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:260)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1305)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1499)
    at com.tcs.srl.stanford.POSWrapper.executePOSTagger(POSWrapper.java:39)
    at com.tcs.srl.stanford.test.POSWrapperTester.ExecutePOSTagger(POSWrapperTester.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I have no clue why this error is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close but not quite right in your diagnosis. Java will always use the first instance of a class in your classpath. However, if you have a heirarchy of classloaders, and a child classloader tries to define a class that a parent has already defined you will get an error like this.

I'm not familiar with the Stanford NER or POS code. However, I can offer some advice.

If you are *convinced* the classes with the same names are identical in the two jars, then just combine the two jars into a single jar - this will remove any duplicates.

If you are worried the NER and POS code might be incompatible, I'd move the source code for the two into a single project, and recompile, carefully inspecting the duplicates.

The alternative is to take the source code from one project and move it into a different package so the class names stay the same, but the packages no longer clash. A good IDE should be able to do this fairly painlessly.

However, for issues like this mailing lists are often the best place to get advice: http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml. I'm sure you won't be the only person to be using these pieces of software together. None of the solutions I mention above should be necessary, so getting advice from someone else who uses them is probably the best.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick inputs. I tried to change the package structure of POS library using Eclipse. Even after changing the package structure my application was not giving ClassNotFoundException. I guess after changing the class structure it was not able to find oen class named 'MaxEntTagger'. Currently I am debugging this POS API and trying to find the answer. I was wondering if its possible to add jars to classpath at runtime. This way I can avoid the above error.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggesting to follow mailing list. There are few people who had faced same problem. Now I am going through those mails. If I get the answer, ill update it here soon. Thanks !!!

Comment: @Shekhar - if you get an answer on the mailing list, do add it hear as a separate answer - I'll be the first to vote for it.

Comment: is there any tutorial which shows how to use NER from java program? Currently I am calling main method if CRFClassifier but every time I call main method, it reloads classifier which is bit time consuming.

Comment: @Shekhar, have you looked at the NERDemo.java file included in the download?  It shows several simple ways to call NER from a Java program.  (Calling the main method every time is definitely wrong for the reason you give; you should load the classifier model only once.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like well known problem and people at Stanford are aware of this problem. I had sent mail on mailing list of NER parser, I got following reply from person called John

> This is a known problem that will be
>   fixed in a week or so.  In the
>   meantime, all of the necessary classes
>   for those two libraries are in
>   StanfordCoreNLP,
>
> John

It seems like they are trying to remove this bug from their API and in the next release of parser and tagger we will get clean API.

Currently I am using CoreNLP package available [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml). This CoreNLP package contains everything from parser, tagger, ner and few other things.

Comment: The first two paragraphs above are correct, but this wasn't an API bug, it's just that the public version of the NER download was too old and the classes used by both the tagger and NER had become incompatible (whereas the classes in the CoreNLP download were naturally all compatible).  At any rate, a new version of Stanford NER that fixes this was released today (!).